# bootstrap-table changes layout set up by bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have just started working on a page that uses bootstrap and bootstrap-table.

Starting with just bootstrap I can select the layout I like using:

```
<table class="table">
```

I then want to add the column sorting functionality from bootstrap-table so I change that to:

```
<table class="table" data-toggle="table">
```

This has the effect of changing the presentation set up by bootstrap.

I then add the sorting attributes:

```
<table class="table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="fname" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="fname" data-sortable="true">First Name
      <th data-field="lname" data-sortable="true">Last Name</th>
```

This functions but each time I click on a new header to select that as my sort column it resizes the width of that column.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use bootstrap-table /without/ changing the presentation layout set up by bootstrap?
2. Is it possible to prevent the changing of column widths when selecting a new sort column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide fixed width with some value to the "td" to achieve that. Like in this case you can provide "width: 33.33%" for three columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css BUT you may have some problems with small responsive versions.

```css
th .caret{
    position:absolute;

}
th{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I cannot understand what do you mean by "changing the presentation layout". Maybe you can remove the css you dont want to use? Can you be more specific?